# MatLab ode45 minimal time step

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode45

I'm trying to solve differential equations with MatLab and ode45 function.
The question is how can I change minimal step size? I want to make it bigger to avoid too small steps.
I'm tryin to do it like this:

```
tspan = [3, 4]; (boundaries of time line)
[t, q] = ode45('dqdt2', tspan, q0);
```

- t - time
- q - solution to find
- dqdt2 - my file with function
- q0 - initial conditions

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but in addition to the suggestion by @drhagen to change tolerances, for ode45 you can set the [`Refine`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#input_argument_d0e709062) parameter to 1 (defaults to 4 in ode45)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

In Matlab, variable step size solvers cannot be given a minimum step size, probably because it doesn't make all that much sense to do so. If you wish to reduce the accuracy of your solution in order to speed up the solution, increase [`RelTol` and `AbsTol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html). With increased tolerance, the solver will generally take larger steps but there will still be no specific minimum step size.

Comment: Thanks, it helps a little bit. Now I'm trying to use tspan =[0,10], but MatLab said "Out of memory" (after few hours of calculating). Maybe I can set number of steps?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the step size for ode45 and other step solvers. When you are defining TSPAN you can specify a set of values that you want the solution for. This will not affect the internal steps taken by the solver but will help the solver in efficient memory management. You can look at the documentation [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_tspan) (Thanks to [edwinksl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/486919/edwinksl) for pointing it out).

```
%Your Code
tspan = [3, 4]; %MATLAB here uses the in built step size

%Set Step size. Say you want a step size of 0.1
tspan = 3:0.1:4;
%This will run over only those values of t that are defined by tspan
```

Comment: "[S]pecify the exact values you want to solve over" sounds misleading. Specifying a `tspan` vector with more than two elements doesn't affect the internal time steps that the solver actually takes. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#inputarg_tspan.

Comment: Good point. Thanks for  pointing that out. Although this approach will help the OP to affect the initial step taken by MATLAB which in turn will help in efficient memory management for large systems (a point noted in the documentation). I will edit my answer to reflect this.